# Angular directives variables deriveded from HTML syntax

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a problem sometimes understanding angular syntax.

This time it is with directives. I know that Angular takes the name of our wanted directives and use it in a camelcase way, example :

In the HTML- ""
in our directive will be shown as " .directive('noUiSlider', [function()....."

does it happens to every variable  in the directive ? I mean :

```html
<no-ui-slider 

                 range-min="500"
                 range-max="5000">

    </no-ui-slider>
```

```
      range-min="500"     ---> will be "rangeMin" ?       
      range-max="5000">   ---> will be "rangeMax" ?
```

It will really help if someone can make it a bit more clear.

Thank's

Comment: yes `range-min` is `rangeMin`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. It is because HTML is not case sensative